# Substituir determinados valores pela media em um DataFrame do pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Olá,

Tenho um DataFrame conforme imagem abaixo. Gostaria de substituir os valores nan da coluna QTDVENDADIARIA pela media dos dois registros anteriores (40+27/2), da mesma forma a coluna preco (2,38+2,38/2) e na coluna EMISSAO onde está o valor NaT colocar a data da Coluna SEQ_DATA. Da mesma forma com o próximo valor Nan da coluna QTDVENDADIARIA (68+54/2) e o PRECO (2,38+2,38/2). Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
df.fillna(df.mean(),axis=1)
```

porém desta forma, ele substitui as medias de toda a coluna, e na de data coloca um valor nada haver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se na linha cujo `index` é igual a zero `QTDVENDADIARIA` for igual `nan` o que o substituirá ?

Comment: Substituíria pela média dos 2 próximos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O fillna não consegue ser tão flexível a ponto de criar uma regra como a sua, nesse caso eu utilizaria o (*iterrows*) para percorrer o dataframe fazer os ajustes.

Seguindo seu exemplo eu criei o seguinte dataframe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E para preencher os campos vazios utilizei o seguinte código:

```
import numpy as np
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if index > 1:

        if pd.isnull(row['QTDVENDADIARIA']):
            df.loc[index, 'QTDVENDADIARIA'] = (df.loc[index-1,'QTDVENDADIARIA']+df.loc[index-2,  'QTDVENDADIARIA'])/2

        if pd.isnull(row['PRECOMEDIODIARIO']):
            df.loc[index, 'PRECOMEDIODIARIO'] = (df.loc[index-1,'PRECOMEDIODIARIO']+df.loc[index-2,'PRECOMEDIODIARIO'])/2

        if pd.isnull(row['EMISSAO']):
            df.loc[index, 'EMISSAO'] = row['SEQ_DATA']

    else:

        if pd.isnull(row['QTDVENDADIARIA']):
            df.loc[index, 'QTDVENDADIARIA'] = (df.loc[index+2,'QTDVENDADIARIA']+df.loc[index+1,  'QTDVENDADIARIA'])/2

        if pd.isnull(row['PRECOMEDIODIARIO']):
            df.loc[index, 'PRECOMEDIODIARIO'] =     (df.loc[index+2,'PRECOMEDIODIARIO']+df.loc[index+1,'PRECOMEDIODIARIO'])/2
```

*Explicando um pouco o código...*

A função iterrows percorre todas as linhas do dataframe, faço isso para saber onde tenho campos em vazio.

Falando somente dos campos de valores, caso o campo esteja vazio faço a conta de média me baseando nos índices das linhas anteriores (-1 e -2).

Quando é o campo de data que está vazio simplesmente copio o dado da coluna (*'SEQ_DATA'*)

O IF inicial serve para checar em qual índice a rotina esta, pois, caso estivesse no índice 0 ou 1, ao tentar fazer o cálculo daria erro ( fiz isso me baseando na resposta do seu comentário e assumindo a mesmo premissa que usou no -0 para 1 também).

Feito isso, esse é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]